# How to know linearlayout has reached its last child item

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

Actually In my project I am dynamically adding a child item inside linearLayout but when last child is reached inside linearLayout i have to load other child same as facebook scrolling. But to know when the last element of linearLayout is arrived?

Comment: May I ask you why aren't you using a ListView?

Comment: Somebody else has worked on this and he has done this way and now I am just following

Comment: You should definitely look into ListView

Comment: @blackbelt is their any way I can achieve this by linearLayout because it require lot of changes and time.

Comment: @Crazy Scrolllistner work only for : GridView, ListView, ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 1):

getChildCount() and also getChildAt() like this may be help you -

```
int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
    for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
          View v = ll.getChildAt(i);

    if(i == (childCount -1)){
    // Do your Task here
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code snip :

```
LinearLayout myLayout;// ur layout 
int childCount = myLayout.getChildCount();
View v = null;
for(int i=0; i<childCount; i++) {
    v = layout.getChildAt(i);
    //do something with your child element
}
```

Comment: @mtentno I want to know while scrolling

Comment: but where every u add child in linear layout u will get the child count with or without scrolling

Comment: @mtentno  when user scroll the LinearLayout and when last item is reached then I want to do some stuff but how I can get user is reached on last item inside linearlayout

Comment: ohh got the question did u implemented onScrollChanged?

Comment: @mtentno no  I didn't implemented onScrollchanged